# Routing without a controller and action name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I've a very basic ASP.NET MVC application that uses the default routing. Now I need to route all the requests that comes with out a specific URL to one action with a single parameter.

Examples:

> www.myapp.com/2374982
>
> www.myapp.com/3242342

should be routed to the same action:

```
public ActionResult ViewById(int id)
```

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just define the route without {controller}/{action} part

```
routes.MapRoute("ById", "{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "ViewById"}, new{id = @"\d+"});
```

The last parameter is constraint, which makes sure that the id is a number.

Comment: Of course I did try this trivial solution. And it doesn't work. I get 404. 

Did you try something like that yourself and it worked??!

Comment: I just tested it, and it works.
Try commenting other route definitions and check controller/action names.

Comment: You are right it was the default routers.MapRoute that did the problem. I just had to reorder them. 

Thanks!